# Как сделать такие элементы?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Как делать такие элементы? (обвел красным) через `after` и `before`? Или через абсолютное позиционирование? И не сломается ли это все при адаптиве?

Comment: а чем плохо сделать такие элементы обычными блоками?

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать обычный блок и повернуть текст с помощью css свойства writing-mode
https://caniuse.com/css-writing-mode

Пример:

```css
section {
  font-family: 'Arial';
  max-height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #464646;
}

.vertical-rl {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

body {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<section class="vertical-rl">
  <p>Вертикальный текст</p>
</section>
```

Comment: Или использовать transform: rotate(-90deg); с префиксами?